# Changing fillStyle to add image to game Object

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a game which fires a gray cannon when I use context.fillStyle but I want to use an image instead of a colour. Using createPattern I get a black cannon (not the image) and console logging the logo as the cannon fires I get repeating img tags. (Which shows its updating):

````
    <img src="cannonball.jpg"> ```



    if (cannonballOnScreen)
   {
      // context.fillStyle = gray
      context.createPattern(logo, 'repeat');
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(cannonball.x, cannonball.y, cannonballRadius,
         0, Math.PI * 2);
      context.closePath();
      context.fill();
   }
````

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, [CanvasRenderingContext2D.createPattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createPattern) requires two arguments, the second is the repeat type.
Try this instead:

```js
var logo = new Image();
logo.src = 'yourFilePath';
logo.onload = function() {
  context.createPattern(logo, 'no-repeat'); // or 'repeat' or 'repeat-x' or 'repeat-y'

};
```

Comment: Thank you sir. However this removed the error it does not actually add the pattern to the canonball object? It is possible I suppose that it is not pulling it in correctly. As when I console log the cannonball I get consistent updates of the img src path...

Comment: Take a look at the link about createPattern, it does not support the first argument simply being a path, you'll need to give it an img element or a ImageBitmap object.

Comment: @SirNail I've added to the answer, you can also select the image tag you added to the question a logo variable with document.querySelector